# How do you access the wordpress mysql database when running it in docker?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

Thanks in advance for helping me out with this. I've been turning myself in circles trying to figure this out, but chances are that I'm missing something really simple.

I followed the quickstart guide to using Wordpress in Docker here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

However, I am having trouble accessing my mysql database.

Here is my docker-compose file (pretty much just copied from the tutorial):

```
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

I am able to get into a shell for my database container by running `docker exec -it db_name /bin/bash`.

Once there, I cannot run mysql. Here are my attempts to do so:

```
root@79f23dc84547:/# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

when I try with the username and password:

```
root@79f23dc84547:/# mysql -u wordpress -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'wordpress'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

the environmental variable was clearly set:

```
root@79f23dc84547:/# echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD    
somewordpress
```

Again, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your client need to run with the same option as your server ([doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html)). Actually for version 5.7 you should remove the option to fix your ([issue](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/313)).

```
#remove
command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
```

Comment: I tried that and got the same result. In fact, I added that line in the first place, because I was getting authentication errors.